# Finding shared items in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

In Google Drive, how do I find all items that I shared with anyone (not only one known particular person)?

I have been sharing individual items to different people, and I now want to clean that up.

Can I un-share everything, and start over?

In advanced search, you have "Not Shared" as an option under "Visibilty". Is there something like "Shared"?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to search `to:` ? (leaving blank after the colon)

It seems to work in my drive.